# Copying or Replacing a part of Column and Row Value in the Cell of a Row of different Column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

**Summary of the Problem:** After doing some preprocessing on one of the part of a csv file from a dataset I have this kind of a dataframe as shown. Further I need extensive preprocessing on it but couldn't getting it properly as per the format.

**Code:**

```py
# Input_DataFrame

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

PMCID_Article = {
    '25763772|t|DCTN4 as a Modifier':["25763772|a|Pseudomonas aeruginosa (Pa)", None],
    'Title' :[None,None],
    'Abstract':[None,None],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(PMCID_Article)
df = df.loc[:, ["25763772|t|DCTN4 as a Modifier","Title","Abstract"]]
print(df)

# Output_reached
            25763772|t|DCTN4 as a Modifier            Title     Abstract
0   25763772|a|Pseudomonas aeruginosa (Pa)             None         None
1                                    None              None         None
```

**Expected Output:** So, from that preprocessed csv file, further I need to separate/split out the first column name and first row cell1 and insert them in their respective heads as depicted below. I have tried to get it by using `loc` and `iloc` but didn't reach the goal. Any kind of solution or suggestion will be helpful.

```py
      PMCID                Title                     Abstract
0  25763772  DCTN4 as a Modifier  Pseudomonas aeruginosa (Pa)
1      None                 None                         None
```